# Unable to send text to textbox element

Tags: java, android, selenium, appium

I am trying to send some text to a Search textbox in an Android app, but it keep returning NoSuchElement exception.

The following is the properties of the element obtained from Appium's element locator.

[image]

And the following is the code to send the text to the searchbox.

```
driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//android.widget.EditText[@content-desc='Search']")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

I have tried by id

```
driver_App.findElement(By.id("header-search")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

by className

```
driver_App.findElement(By.className("android.widget.EditText")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

and to a certain extent, the following :

```
new WebDriverWait(driver_App, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.xpath("//*[@id='header-search']")));
driver_App.findElement(By.xpath("//*[@id='header-search']")).sendKeys("ABC");
```

None of the above could send the string "ABC" to the textbox element, and returned a NoSuchElement exception.

Hope to have advice on what I may have done wrong and possible solutions.

Note:
Added the following screenshot of the complete tree structure for the element Search.

[image]

Comment: how about `driver_App.findElementByAccessibilityId("Search").sendText("...");`?

Comment: Hi @Vault23, I have tried your suggestion, and sad to report that it didn't work either. Is there any difference if I use ,sendKeys() and .sendText() ?

Comment: i mixed up method names, `sendKeys()` is correct. In this case i suggest that something wrong with particular locator. Could you please paste whole tree for this element so we will be able to see full path for it?

Comment: @Vault23I have attached the screenshot from UIAutomator. Hope this helps.

Comment: this is very strange, the only difference of attributes i see is **long-clickable** attribute that set to false (compared to some random text field in other application). So i would recommend you to compare attributes some other text field of your application with that.

Comment: @Vault23 I shall check with the dev team whether they can change it to "true" for long-clickable. True enough, many textboxes have long-clickable as "True". However, is the clickable properties causing no such element found issue, since clickable, I think, refers to whether the text field is clickable or not. I may be wrong, and hope to have your advice.

Answer (score 0):

Thee are few ways to send a string to a text field in mobile.

Some of the android text needs to be click first.

```
new WebDriverWait(driver_App, 30).until(ExpectedConditions.presenceOfElementLocated(By.id("header-search")));
driver_App.findElement (By.id("header-search")).click();
driver_App.findElement (By.id("header-search")).sendKeys ("ABC");
```

Comment: Hi @john, I tried adding the ".click()", but unfortunately, it is still returning NoSuchElement exception.

Comment: Use setvalue or execute javascript to send . See if these work ?

Comment: I have tried using setValue, and sadly, it did not work as well. However, I think the main issue was it fails to find the element. I shall try the javascript method and let you know the result soon.